# You do not have permission to open the application “Anaconda-Navigator”

Tags: permissions, anaconda, jupyter

I was working on my Jupyter notebook. Looking for a better way to organize the folders and notebooks. When I must have pressed something wrong, I now have no more files on my computer (they're still in the Cloud). Whenever I try to open anaconda, it gives me a "You do not have permission to open the application “Anaconda-Navigator message. If I try to start Jupyter from the terminal, it doesn't recognize it. does this sound familiar?.”

Comment: Please check the environment in which your anaconda is installed and run it in the same.